# Sliding Glass Door Locked from the Outside?

Tags: doors

How in the world could a sliding glass door lock on your from the outside.  I only open it at the handle and do not touch the latch or pin.  This happened to me recently and got locked out while out on my patio.  The lock to the sliding glass door in on the inside!

Comment: Loose [hook deadlock](https://www.google.com/search?q=hook+deadlock&tbm=isch) and slamming it too hard maybe?

Comment: Are the door channels clean? How about the wheels? It may be getting stuck, rather than actually locking.

Comment: All I did was open and shut it and it locked me out of my apartment and the management company is making me pay for them to having to break a window for me to get back in as my front door I had deadbolted which of course I do.  With them doing nothing I fear this is going to happen again as they say it is working properly and the manager's resolution is to not shut the door all the way

Answer (score 2):

The latch mechanism ("hook deadlock" as mentioned by CactusCake) is generally installed so that the "hook" is facing up. But sometimes people install them upside down to where the hook faces down and if it is loose and sloppy, the hook falls down when you shut the door, locking you out.

Normal:
[image]

Upside down:
[image]

Comment: It is installed facing up